# Type Geometry is not a defined system type

Tags: sql-server, geometry

I am simply running this query and get the error in title

```
INSERT  [dbo].[PROPERTY] ([GPSId] ,[Energy],[corp_type],[irrigation],[variety],[trees],[utilizat],[number] ,[address],[water_hour],[owner_ID] ,[w_source],[w_inche],[Area] ,[Pool],[NoeMalekiat],[MotevasetBardasht]  ,[w_dore],[Shape],[idshahrestan],[idostan],[contex],[title])  VALUES ('WR-2627-4BS','هیچ کدام','درخت سیب','غرقابی','Null',0,'باغ','4','مهرگرد',90,1209504774,'چشمه',0,670.172195242369,1,'شش دانگ',0,0,Geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((550480.3407000020000000 3492052.1042000000000000, 550484.4087000050000000 3492054.7619999900000000, 550491.0337000000000000 3492050.1400000000000000, 550471.1482000160000000 3492031.7781000200000000, 550467.5869000140000000 3492032.8482000100000000, 550449.0791000050000000 3492051.8504000100000000, 550450.4848000070000000 3492058.8710999900000000, 550454.7364000020000000 3492064.5679000100000000, 550475.6995000040000000 3492052.7600000100000000, 550483.2033000110000000 3492053.9946000000000000, 550480.3407000020000000 3492052.1042000000000000))',32639).MakeValid(),13,14,2,6)
```

this is the version of sql server I am using

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4042.0 (X64) 
Mar 26 2015 21:18:04 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

this is my table create sql

```
    USE [land_gis]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PROPERTY]    Script Date: 1/27/2016 6:21:31 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROPERTY](
    [OBJECTID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GPSId] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Energy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [corp_type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Pool] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [irrigation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [variety] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [trees] [int] NULL,
    [utilizat] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [number] [smallint] NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [water_hour] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [owner_ID] [numeric](38, 8) NOT NULL,
    [w_source] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [w_inche] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [Area] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [pool_cap] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [discript] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Shape] [geometry] NULL,
    [w_dore] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [idshahrestan] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [idostan] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [contex] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [title] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [NoeMalekiat] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MotevasetBardasht] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [R14_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OBJECTID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 75) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

this is compatibility level

```
    USE [land_gis]
GO
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'land_gis';
GO
```

the result is

```
100
```

I know the error is because of version of sqlserver but as far as I know SQL server 2008 R2 supports geometry type..Could you please help me with it?

thank you so much

Answer,
I should change `Geometry` to `geometry`

Comment: Hmm....this seems to work on my 2008 instance. The only difference is you are running express and I am running standard.

Comment: `(1 row(s) affected)`... BTW add for Unicode strings `N` prefix (`'هیچ کدام'`)

Comment: @SeanLange does these versions have any different?what can I do with is?

Comment: @Devart Thank you..do you use express or standard version?and also how can I add N prefix?thank you

Comment: I use `SQL Server 2008R2 SP3 Developer edition`. Add manually for your query `N'unicode'`

Comment: @Devart do you think if I reinstall it would work fine?

Comment: Check the compatibility level and please provide your error message...

Comment: @Devart I have updated the question..It results 100

Comment: Yes, but without error message ;)

Comment: @Devart which error message?The only error message is Type Geometry is not a defined system type ..compatibility level does not return any error

Comment: Are you able to run the following SQL statement by itself; basically creating just a geometry variable? `declare @geom geometry
set @geom = Geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON (...)',32639)`

Comment: @Devart I have found the problem..I should write geometry not with G..Do you know why?

Comment: @PeterTirrell I can only run if I change to geometry..Why?